# Using qrcode with koma variables?

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, qrcode

Is there a way to create a qr code in LaTeX with koma variables as input?

am using the package `qrcode` and everything works fine and the package is easy to use. However, when I am trying to use a koma variable as the input for the text LaTeX crashes.

This works:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@it.is}

\newcommand{\texttoconvert}{mailto:me@it.is}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
        \qrcode[height=1.5cm]{\texttoconvert}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

But this does not:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@it.is}

\newcommand{\texttoconvert}{mailto:\usekomavar{fromemail}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
        \qrcode[height=1.5cm]{\texttoconvert}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Why is that? It also does not work to use koma variables directly in qrcode...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construct macro from komavar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532866/construct-macro-from-komavar)

Comment: I contacted Markus Kohm (the author of koma-script) and he discourages that solution. I wanted to post his preferred solution here but my question is closed therefore I can't...

Comment: I’ve voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the solution that the author of koma-script intended. Also it is imho the cleanest and shortest and most understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked to Markus Kohm (author of koma-script) and he told me that the intended solution with koma-script is to  use the ability of `\usekomavar` to expand the koma-variable into the first parameter of the optional variable `\usekomavar[<command>]{<komavariable>}`.

Like this:

```
\newcommand*{\qrcodewithprefix}[2][mailto:]{\qrcode{#1#2}}
\usekomavar[\qrcodewithprefix]{fromemail}
```

or even shorter:

```
\usekomavar[\def\fromemail]{fromemail}
\qrcode{mailto:\fromemail}
```

His main reason for this are that this solution (compared to the more low level solutions) enables helpful error messages.

If you try a typo in the koma-variable and write `\usekomavar[\def\fromemail]{frommail}` instead you get the following error message:

```
Class scrlttr2 Error: KOMA-Script variable not defined. \usekomavar[\def\fromemail]{frommail}
```

This does not happen if you instead used:

```
\def\fromemail{example-\csname scr@fromemail@var\endcsname}
```

When you introduce a typo then you only get a very confusing:

```
Undefined control sequence. \qrcode{mailto:\fromemail}
```

To sum it up the easy and clean solution is to define `\fromemail` and with `\usekomavar` expand the contents of the koma-variable `fromemail` into it and from then on use `\fromemail` instead of the koma-variable when needing the expanded variant:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{john@doe.com}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}
\usekomavar[\def\fromemail]{fromemail}
\begin{document}
    \qrcode{mailto:\fromemail}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately `\usekomavar` is not fully expandable, see its doc in Koma-Script manual (2022-10-12), sec. *4.5. Variables*.

But `\usekomavar` accepts a "styling" command as its optional argument, which will act on the value of variable.  That is, after `\setkomavar{<name>}{<content>}`,

```tex
\usekomavar[\mycmd]{<name>}
% is equivalent to
\mycmd{<content>}
```

Apply this trick to OP's use case:

```tex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@it.is}

\newcommand{\QRmailto}[2][]{\qrcode[#1]{mailto:#2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
      \usekomavar[{\QRmailto[height=1.5cm]}]{fromemail}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since now the text to be encoded in qr code is tokenized before passed to `\qrcode`, special characters (`#$&^_~%␣\{}`) may need to be escaped (`\#\$\&\^\_\~\%\␣\\\{\}`), see `qrcode` package doc (2015/01/08 v1.51), sec. 2.3 *Special characters*.

```tex
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@it.is}

%    \myQrcode[<opts>]{<pre>}{<post>}{<text>}
% => \qrcode  [<opts>]{<pre><text><post>}
\newcommand{\myQrcode}[4][]{\qrcode[#1]{#2#4#3}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
      \usekomavar
        [{\myQrcode[height=1.5cm]
                   {mailto:}
                   {?subject=ABC/123&body=Hello\ and\ welcome}}]
        {fromemail}
      % <QR code requested for "mailto:me@it.is?subject=ABC/123&body=Hello and welcome" in version 0-M.>
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work and is very simple. However, it does no longer work when I want to add subject and text as in `\newcommand{\QRmailto}[2][]{\qrcode[#1]{mailto:#2?subject=ABC/123&body=Hello and welcome,}}`. Then the spaces in the body are omitted. Why?

Comment: @mrCarnivore According to `qrcode` doc, using `\ ` does the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the help you have given me! escaping the spaces does work. I was confused since it worked when using plain text in qrcode without needing to escape the spaces.

Answer (score 5):

The `\usekomavar` command is not expandable. You can define an expandable version (that won't check whether the variable is actually defined, beware).

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[final]{qrcode}

\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@it.is}

\newcommand{\texttoconvert}{mailto:\expkomavar{fromemail}}

\makeatletter
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\expkomavar}{sO{\@firstofone}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% \expkomavar*
    \expkomavar@name{#2}{#3}%
  }{% \expkomavar
    \expkomavar@var{#2}{#3}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\expkomavar@name}[2]{#1{\@nameuse{scr@#2@name}}}
\newcommand{\expkomavar@var}[2]{#1{\@nameuse{scr@#2@var}}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{}

\qrcode[height=1.5cm]{\texttoconvert}

\bigskip

\qrcode[height=1.5cm]{mailto:me@it.is}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The two QR-codes are the same, as witnessed by the log file where we find

```
<Reading QR code for "mailto:me@it.is" at level 2-Q from aux file.>
```

for the second instance, meaning that the package recognizes it's the same as a previously built one.

Comment: Thank you. Although the definition is more complicated than the other answer, I will accept this one because the usage is easier.

Comment: You might make a feature request to the class author.

Comment: To the class author of qrcode or of koma-script?

Comment: @mrCarnivore koma-script